# query posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I want to filter my query results just before the_loop starts in word press. I only want the results having term_id or term_taxonomy_id equal to 1.

```
query_posts('post_type=my_post&term_id=1&posts_per_page=6');
```

This is returning all rows, I am new to word press so I am not sure that we can use term_id in query_posts. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What is the taxonomy for the `term_id` ?

Comment: name of taxonomy is I am giving in post_type=my_posts(taxonomy name).

Comment: This is post type not the taxonomy, in which taxonomy your custom posts belong to ?

Comment: I have not created custom post type, I have created one custom taxonomy using register_taxonomy function and this taxonomy is in `wp_term_taxonomy` table. Its giving results for all terms from table wp_terms. My url : http://base/taxonomy_name/slug_of_term. But taxonomy.php page is not giving correct results so I am re writing query again.

Comment: What is the taxonomy name you've used when you registered it ?

Comment: `register_taxonomy(
   'mumG',
   'mumT',
   array(
    'label' => __( 'Label' ),
    'show_ui' => false,
   )
  );`                                                                            mumG is in wp_taxonomy_term table,                                                                           mumT is i am using in post_type=mumT,                                                             My URl : base/mumG/term_slug.                                                                 so I want to get result only beloning to this slug

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the post type is not the taxonomy, post type is basically `post`, `page`, `Attachment`, `Revision`, `Navigation Menu` and the `Custom Post Types` and to create a custom post type we use `register_post_type()`, so you didn't create a custom post type (that I've got from your comments) instead, you've created a custom taxonomy using [register_taxonomy()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) function and in this case the first parameter in the `register_taxonomy()` is the taxonomy name and the second parameter is the name of the object type for the taxonomy and object-types can be built-in Post Type or any Custom Post Type that may be already registered. So, according to your given example bellow

```
register_taxonomy( 
    'mumG', 
    'mumT', 
    array( 
        'label' => __( 'Label' ),
        'show_ui' => false,
    ) 
);
```

In the code above, you have created a custom taxonomy and it's name is `mumG` and the second parameter `mumT` is used as the object type for the taxonomy and it seems there is no such an object (post_type) in the `WordPress` unless you don't register/create one custom post type using [register_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) function. So, if you don't want to create a custom post type for this taxonomy, then you should use the built-in post type `post` in the place of `mumT` as post type and can use following `query` to retrieve

```
$args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'post', // if post_type is post
        'showposts' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'mumG',
            'terms' => 1,
            'field' => 'term_id',
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC' 
);
query_posts( $args );
```

Otherwise, if you want to use a custom post type, then you have to create a custom post type first and then use the name of the custom post in the place of `post` (the second parameter) like

```
register_taxonomy( 
    'mumG', 
    'yourCustomPostName', // if you have a post_type of 'yourCustomPostName'
    ......
);
```

and use `'post_type' => 'yourCustomPostName'` in the query. Please read these documentations for better understanding, [register_taxonomy()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy), [register_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) and [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) on the Codex.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace taxonomy category name (sliders_category) to your taxonomy category name.**

```
$args = array(
                'tax_query' => array(
                                    array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'sliders_category',
                                            'field' => 'id',
                                            'terms' => '1'
                                          )

                            ),
                'post_type'=>'my_post',
                'order'=>'ASC',
                'posts_per_page'=>6

                );

query_posts($args);
```